# pyorient can't connect to orientdb docker

Tags: python, orientdb, pyorient

I'm using pyorient 1.5.4 and the docker for orientdb 2.2.5

If I use the browser to connect to the database, the server is clearly running.
If I connect with pyorient, I get an error.

Here is the code I use to connect to the database:

```
import pyorient

database = pyorient.OrientDB('127.0.0.1', 2424)
database.db_open(
                'myDB',
                'root',
                'mypassword',
                db_type='graph'
            )
```

I get the following error:

```
pyorient.exceptions.PyOrientConnectionException: Server seems to have went down
```

I created the docker container with the following command:

```
docker run -d --name orientdb -p 2424:2424 -p 2480:2480 -v /home/myuser/Code/database:/orientdb/databases  -e ORIENTDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=mypassword orientdb:latest /orientdb/bin/server.sh  -Ddistributed=true
```

The server is running because connecting via the browser works fine.

It seems like the necessary ports are open so why does pyorient thinks the database is closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my problem. I was starting the docker container with:

```
-Ddistributed=true
```

removing the parameter enabled me to connect just fine.

However, I have found that pyorient gets into an infinite loop when trying to parse the packets that's returned from orientDB under distributed mode. This is due to a bug on pyorient. The bug is explained in more detail over here:

https://github.com/mogui/pyorient/issues/215#issuecomment-245007336